# Why does plurality program not pass check50? cs50 week 3

Tags: c, debugging, ide, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes ++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election printwinner(void)
void print_winner(void)
{
    int temp = candidates[0].votes;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes >= temp)
        {
            temp = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < candidate_count; x++)
    {
        if (temp == candidates[x].votes)
        {
            printf("Winner: %s\n", candidates[x].name);
        }
    }

}
```

Check50 says:

:( print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
Cause
print_winner function did not print both winners of election

:( print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
Cause
print_winner function did not print all three winners of election

My program prints multiple winners in case of a tie as well as in case of all candidates winning!

Comment: You might find folks more familiar with cs50 issues here: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ If you keep your question here you should explain what your code does and provide some sample input, expected output, and the incorrect output.

Comment: Where in the specification does it say winners will be preamble-announced with the string `"Winner: "` ? Follow the specification **to the letter**.

Comment: Your title contains a spelling mistake. Please edit and remove the second "does"